# After my VWP to the US expires, can I travel to nearby countries?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, caribbean

When my VWP expires, can I travel to Canada, Mexico or Caribbean Islands without staying "illegal"? I don't want to re-enter the US again and re-start the clock, I would fly home after this. I am not sure if I would travel legally as those countries are within the VWP zone.

Comment: You can certainly travel to another country (Canada and Mexico are not adjacent islands, or islands at all for that matter) if you follow whatever process is required for you to enter those countries, which may include a visa depending on your nationality. Where you can run into trouble is if you use up your 90 days, travel to, say, Canada, and want to come back into the US to catch a flight home.

Comment: To underscore @ZachLipton's point: there's no such thing as a VWP zone. The VWP allows you to enter the US only. The fact that a short trip to (for example) Canada doesn't reset the clock is simply to prevent people from using Canada to abuse the VWP. It implies nothing about authorization to enter Canada.

Comment: The only Caribbean islands that would fall under VWP rules would be Puerto Rico and the US Virgin Islands.  All the other islands are separate countries / territories.  But you do need to keep in mind that any flight "home" that transits through the USA requires entering the USA again.

Comment: Yes, you can. There is no VWP zone or complex rules that would apply to all these countries. There are special rules for people reentering the US after having been to Canada, Mexico, etc. but that's entirely a US thing, not something agreed with the countries in question, which all have their own immigration regime (including different visa requirements and different maximum length for short visits – don't assume you can necessarily stay 90 days!)

Comment: @Tom is Bahamas not under the VWP rules?

Comment: @Sarah- Bahamian citizens enter the US under a visa waiver but it is different than the VWP that applies to other countries.  But having a US visa waiver does not effect entering the Bahamas, as they are tied to the UK not USA.

Answer (score 5):

You're considered to have left the US at the recorded departure time of your flight which leaves the US to any other country. You need to depart within the 90 days stay granted when you originally entered the US.

The 90 day clock everyone refers to begins when you receive your admitted stamp on entry to the US, and it's only relevant if you re-enter the US before the 90 days ends, but have only traveled to Canada, Mexico or the named Caribbean islands. When you do this, you're readmitted under the previous admission and must depart before the end of the original 90 day period, again to any country.

If you travel elsewhere, or you remain outside the US past the end of the original 90 days, then return to the US, then if you are admitted it will start a new 90 day period. But if you return too soon after the first 90 day period ended, you will attract the attention of CBP officers and likely be questioned more closely about your travel plans.

The purpose of this is simply to prevent visa runs, where someone exits the US for a few days and then returns, in order to live or work in the US without having been admitted for that purpose.

Note well that this can affect your travel plans if you need to *transit* the US in order to return home. The US does not have sterile transit areas; you must be cleared through immigration even to transit.